# Derivative of a function with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I need to calculate derivative of the following function with respect to the matrix X:

$f(X)=||diag(X^TX)||_2^2$

where $diag()$ returns diagonal elements of a matrix into a vector. How can I calculate $\frac {\partial f(X)} {\partial X}$? Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the Hadamard ($\circ$) and Frobenius ($:$) products, the function can be written as
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= \|I\circ(X^TX)\|^2_F \cr
   &= I\circ(X^TX):I\circ(X^TX) \cr
   &= I\circ(X^TX)\circ I:(X^TX) \cr
   &= I\circ I\circ(X^TX):(X^TX) \cr
   &= I\circ(X^TX):(X^TX) \cr
   &= I:(X^TX)\circ(X^TX) \cr
}$$
The differential of which is
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= I:2\,(X^TX)\circ d(X^TX) \cr
    &= 2\,I\circ(X^TX):d(X^TX) \cr
    &= 2\,I\circ(X^TX):(dX^TX+X^TdX) \cr
    &= 2\,I\circ(X^TX):2\,{\rm sym}(X^TdX) \cr
    &= 4\,{\rm sym}(I\circ(X^TX)):X^TdX \cr
    &= 4\,X(I\circ(X^TX)):dX \cr
}$$
Since $df = \big(\frac {\partial f} {\partial X}\big):dX\,\,$ the derivative must be
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= 4\,X(I\circ(X^TX)) \cr
}$$
It helps to know a few simple rules for manipulating these products.

Unlike the regular matrix product, both the Hadamard and Frobenius products are commutative
$$ \eqalign {
 A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
 A:B &= B:A \cr
}$$
They also satisfy these mixed-product rules
$$ \eqalign {
 A:BC &= AC^T:B \cr
 A:BC &= B^TA:C \cr
 A\circ B:C &= A:B\circ C \cr
}$$
The latter being sort of an element-wise triple (scalar) product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do mean with sym? The result of derivative in your answer has the same size as the matrix $X$. but I think that the derivative should have the size of $X^T$.

Comment: The shape of the derivative is a matter of preference, or convention. The sym operation extracts the symmetric part of the matrix:  ${\rm sym}(X) = {\frac{1}{2}}(X+X^T).\,\,$  Just as the skew operation extracts the skew-symmetric part:  ${\rm skew}(X) = {\frac{1}{2}}(X-X^T)$

Comment: According to the definition of sym operation, $X$ must be a square matrix.   But how about a m-by-n matrix? Does the derivative change for this case?

Comment: In the current problem, the matrix of interest is $X^TX$ which _is_ a square matrix. For non-square matrices, lots of operations are undefined, e.g. sym, trace, det, $X^3$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here you get a scalar function of the matrix $X$. The derivative of such a scalar function is defined as the matrix of partial derivatives wrt each entry of the matrix, as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix).

You can expand out the expression and calculate the partial derivative.